# Bounced email on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm developing application for google app engine (python), witch needs not only to send emails, but also know which ones bounce back.

I created special account for my domain noreply@example.com, added it as an app admin and sending messages from it.

The problem is (and it was described here http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1800) - GAE sets the Return-Path to some internal email address, not allowing to receive bounced email messages.

Anyone aware of any possible workaround for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like someone bypassed this problem by switching to [Yahoo's Mail API](http://developer.yahoo.com/mail/), which uses OAuth and can be used over HTTP. Until google fixes your problem, this looks like a viable solution.

Answer (score 2):

Until the issue is resolved, workaround for my project is using [typhoonae](http://code.google.com/p/typhoonae/), bind mail service to google app's gmail as SMTP (to send messages from noreply@example.com). When sending this way, noreply@example.com receives bounced messages.

Answer (score 2):

Google has actually since added [a method for receiving bounced messages](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/bounce) via an HTTP Request. It requires adding to your app.yaml:

```
inbound_services:
- mail_bounce
```

Which will cause a request to hit `/_ah/bounce` each time a bounce is received. You can then handle the bounce by adding a handler for it. See the section [there](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/bounce) on Handling Bounce Notifications for more details on how to glean the additional information from those requests.

Answer (score 1):

You could use use a third party "email marketing" API like [CampaignMonitor](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/api) that keeps track of the bounced addresses:
http://www.campaignmonitor.com/api/method/subscribers-getbounced/

But you'd have to send mail through them, and sync your user list with theirs through their API.